# Any help functions provided to programmatically write to Docpad.coffee?

Tags: docpad

I'm using Docpad and want to do increment a counter (for cachebusting of assets) every time a static site is generated.

I figured the easiest way would be t:

- hook into `docpad.coffee.writeBefore`
- increment a counter `templateData.assetCounter`
- persist docpad.coffee.

Still figuring out the functionality that comes out-of-the-box with Docpad, so looking for a way to persist docpad.coffee to disk. Would that be a good idea at all? 
Of course I could read/ write to disk using require('fs') but that may conflict/race with what docpad may internally be already doing (just guessing)

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really cool idea! A plugin would be great for this, it could:

- hook into `docpadReady` to load the persisting file
- hook into `extendTemplateData` to add the current counter value to the template data
- hook into `writeAfter` to increment the counter and save it to the persisting file
- the persisting file could just be `my-website/generateCounter.json`

This way you don't have to modify your `docpad.coffee` file after each generation :)